# Twitter share link mobile issue

Tags: html, twitter

I'm creating a Twitter share link. It works fine on desktop but for mobile its behaving differently.

Here is the Twitter share link

```html
<a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=this%20a%20is%20a%20test" target="_blank"><svg class="twitter social_icon--twitter" ><use xlink:href="#icon-twitter"></use></svg></a>
```

It's just opening up the site without pre-filling the content.

Any ideas of possible fix, workaround or explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using https://twitter.com/intent/tweet in the url seemed to fix the issue.

Seems like  "/home/?status= URLs" doesn't work anymore.

http://www.geoffmanning.com/twitter/url-encode-a-twitter-status-message/

Answer (score 5):

EDITED:

This link seems to work: `twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=this%20a%20is%20a%20test`

Comment: Did try doing this but the issue still remains the behavior is the same.

Comment: The linked page being invalid was the exact reason for the question, which means that the link is itself the answer.